# Spark Streaming AvailableNow trigger for Azure Event Hub?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to use spark streaming with `availableNow` trigger to ingest data from an Azure Event Hub into a Delta Lake table in Databricks.

My code:

```
conn_str = "my conn string"
ehConf = {
  "eventhubs.connectionString": 
    spark.sparkContext._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(conn_str),
  "eventhubs.consumerGroup":
    "my-consumer-grp",
}

read_stream = spark.readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()

stream = read_stream.writeStream \
  .format("delta") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_location) \
  .trigger(availableNow=True) \
  .toTable(full_table_name, mode="append")
```

According to the documentation https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers
The `availableNow` trigger should process all data currently available, in a micro-batch style.

However, This is not happening, instead, it processes only 1000 rows.
The output of the stream tells the story:

```
{
"sources" : [ {
    "description" : "org.apache.spark.sql.eventhubs.EventHubsSource@2c5bba32",
    "startOffset" : {
      "my-hub-name" : {
        "0" : 114198857
      }
    },
    "endOffset" : {
      "my-hub-name" : {
        "0" : 119649573
      }
    },
    "latestOffset" : {
      "my-hub-name" : {
        "0" : 119650573
      }
    },
    "numInputRows" : 1000,
    "inputRowsPerSecond" : 0.0,
    "processedRowsPerSecond" : 36.1755236407047
  } ]
}
```

We can clearly see the offset changes by way more than the 1000 processed. 
I have verified the content of the target table, it contains the last 1000 offsets. \

According to the Event Hub configuration for Pyspark https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/PySpark/structured-streaming-pyspark.md#event-hubs-configuration 
The `maxEventsPerTrigger` is set to `1000*partitionCount` by default, this should only affect how many events are processed per batch though, and not the total amount of records processed by `availableNow` trigger.

Running the same query with the trigger being `once=True` will instead ingest **all** of the events (assuming batch size is set large enough).

Is seems like the `availableNow` trigger is not working as intended for Azure Event Hub.

Comment: I raised an issue about this on azure-event-hubs-spark github.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/issues/656
I'm suspecting they have not implemented this trigger support yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'avaiableNow' trigger seems to not be implemented yet in 'azure-event-hub-spark' package.

But there is a **workaround** possible using Kafka connector to Azure Event Hub - https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-for-kafka/tree/master/tutorials/spark

So essentially the previous code becomes

```
bootstrap_servers = "my-evh-namespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093"
eventhub_endpoint = "my-evh-namespace-endpoint"

# The 'kafkashaded' part here is because it's running in Databricks.
# Otherwise drop that part.
EH_SASL = f"kafkashaded.org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"$ConnectionString\" password=\"{eventhub_endpoint}\";"

topic = "my-eventhub-name"

read_stream = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN") \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL") \
    .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", EH_SASL) \
    .option("subscribe", topic) \
    .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1000) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .option("includeHeaders", "true") \
    .load()

# Notice that the output writeStream remains the same.
stream = read_stream.writeStream \
  .format("delta") \
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpoint_location) \
  .trigger(availableNow=True) \
  .toTable(full_table_name, mode="append")
```

This results in the stream performing as expected - ingesting all events up until start time in batches of size `maxOffsetsPerTrigger`