# how to run streaming job for a certain time? pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a script to run streaming job to read the data from eventhub and need to limit the running time to 10 minutes. And this script will be executed every 12 hours.

This is the code to do the job.

```
streamer = (
spark.readStream.format("eventhubs")
.options(**ehConf)
.load()
.writeStream.foreachBatch(write_to_parquet_table)
.option(
    "checkpointLocation",
    eventhub_checkpoint_location,
)
.outputMode("update")
.start()
 )
streamer.awaitTermination()
```

How can I make it run only for 10 minutes and stop?

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Hops this helps you
https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/streaming.html#StreamingQuery.awaitTermination

I think you need to pass seconds in awaitTermination

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to consume data regularly and then terminate, then you just need to use appropriate [trigger](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers) - add `.trigger(once=True)` before `.start()` instead of running it indefinitely (default mode).

Please note that EventHubs connector [doesn't support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74025485/spark-streaming-availablenow-trigger-for-azure-event-hub) more flexible `AvailableNow` trigger. If you want to have it, then it's better to switch to the Kafka connector that is shipped together with Databricks Runtimes (and it's more stable!)